# How to negotiate relocation expenses (for a postdoc in the UK) two months after I accepted the offer?

Tags: postdocs, united-kingdom

I was offered a UKRI funded position. It was advertised  as two positions. I negotiated my salary given my experience and the PI refused. Since I am International, I was waiting for my visa so I attended some meetings with the team. During these meetings, I realised that my level is much higher than other postdoc who clearly did not know a lot of stuff.

Unfortunately, no one instructed me on negotiation process, I thought it is all about salary. I did not even know about relocation negotiation. I am not comfortable and I honestly want to reject this offer.
It is my first opportunity to work. I need it but I feel I deserved more.

Can I negotiate my relocation expenses to be covered?
How to negotiate relocation expenses? What if it failed?

Should I reject the offer or accept it just because I do not have any other opportunity? I am not comfortable doing a job and I know I should have more.

Comment: Where I work (not UK), there is no negotiation possible on a postdoc salary - it is defined by HR to apply to all postdocs. If you want to reject, then reject it.

Comment: In general there is very limited scope for negotiating academic salaries in the UK, especially at the post-doc level. Relocation is often an administrative policy depending on the position & length of contract. So there is probably limited scope to negotiate this too. But you could (should) ask about it if you need it.

Comment: @JonCuster I need the position. Many people told me to trust my gut and reject it. Others told me to be grateful. I am confused

Answer (score 5):

After the update to the question I will turn my comment into an answer.

In general there is very limited scope for negotiating academic salaries in the UK, especially at the post-doc level. There is a [national pay scale](https://www.ucu.org.uk/he_singlepayspine) which constrains the salaries possible for a particular job category ('band' or 'grades') fairly tightly. You can often find these pay ranges by searching 'University Name Pay Scale'. See example [here](https://www.exeter.ac.uk/media/universityofexeter/humanresources/documents/payroll/Pay_Scales.pdf) (not my institution). The Band/Grade will often (but not always) be mentioned in the job advertisement. It would be exceptionally difficult (impossible) to negotiate a salary outside the pay band of the job in question. In most cases you would get a salary at the lower end of the pay band since you increase by one 'point' per year and would then get stuck at the top of the band unless you got promoted to the next 'band'/'grade' (unlikely for a short-term post-doc since this would mean promotion to a permanent faculty position).

Relocation is often an administrative policy depending on the position & length of contract. So there is probably limited scope to negotiate this. But you could (should) ask about it if you need it. At my institution you would need at least a 1 year contract to qualify for relocation (among other requirements). This is managed by our HR department.

Note that UKRI funds are quite restricted in what they can be used for, so it usually isn't possible to pay more salary or relocation from research funds.

We can't say if you should accept the job or not. But make sure your expectations are realistic based on how academic pay/benefits work in the UK.

Comment: It is two year contract. In the advertisement, salary was posted as a range. I negotiated but got rejected . I honestly think about negotiating relocation expenses but I don't know if it is good or bad thing to do? They are waiting for my visa for two months? This is why I do not want to reject the offer anymore.

Comment: @Samo, as I mentioned in my answer. Negotating relocation expenses is likely not possible (there would be a specific amount available depending on position/length of contract). You should ask what is available for your case. Visas in the UK take a long time at present unfortunately ... I have heard of much longer than two months.

Comment: @Samo. Also note the top of the salary range should be interpreted as 'exceptional candidate.' For example someone with several years of very relevant post-doctoral research experience.

Comment: @atom44 - perhaps not so much 'exceptional' as 'already experienced' (i.e. second postdoc)?

Comment: I have experience but in my country not UK. Is not this considered as experience? Some told me it is not considered as experience as long as not in UK

Comment: @Samo, Experience would not need to be UK based (many are hired with non-UK experience). How much the experience is valued - only the PI could decide that depending on their needs for the project.

Comment: @JonCuster, I would say that would be the case as a minimum. Not necessarily sufficient to get the top of the advertised range. I would imagine the criteria to get to the top of the range varies quite widely. It has never happened for the post-doc hiring I've been involved in, so seems quite rare in my experience.

Comment: @samo You say the project is UKRI-funded. This means the PI has been awarded a fixed amount of money. Often there simply isn't any money available to pay someone a higher salary - even if the PI wants to - except perhaps by shortening the duration of the post.

Comment: Do you think I should negotiate my relocation expenses @avid

Comment: You have little to lose by asking what they'll help with.

Comment: It was not in my offer. How should I start the conversation? Can I email my supervisor to ask if he can cover my relocation expenses. @avid

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [atom44](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/41443/atom44)'s answer that there is usually a very limited opportunity to negotiate postdoc salary in the UK (see also [my other answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/166590/i-couldnt-negotiate-my-postdoc-salary-during-hr-meeting-should-i-try-days-late/166593#166593)).

Regarding the relocation expenses, your University should have a policy on that. Sometimes relocation is covered for all new staff, sometimes only for permanent, sometimes only for lecturers and above, sometimes only for international, sometimes only for local. This is not in your offer, because it is in the "collective agreement" which is an internal document negotiated by University senior management, staff unions and sometimes academic Senate. HR will know the rules and will tell you whether they can reimburse your relocation from the Uni's budget. Importantly, this is not the UKRI budget, which your PI is responsible for. This is why you should ask HR, not PI, about it (but you can cc your PI in the email of course).

Comment: When I emailed them asking about accommodation for staff, they told me, this is relocation and it was not in your offer @Dmitry savostyanov

Comment: Too bad. Unfortunately, this is a sad reality of many UK Unis - they advertise their "international outlook" to attract international students and their high tuition fees, but they don't show much support for their international staff.

Comment: Yes, that is why I thought I should negotiate with the PI because PI asked about the offer

Comment: It is not a bad idea - sometimes there may be some money under-spent in their UKRI budget which in principle could be spent to cover your relocation. But this is assuming there are actually money to spend and also that your PI is keen enough to ask UKRI's approval to re-purpose the funds, which is not an automatic process.